# How to enlarge an image on hover or click?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a stack of images using HTML and CSS, that if I hover or click on any of them, it will be enlarged in the same page. This is what I've been able to do:

```
<img src ="mark1.jpg" height="150" width="300" /> 
<img src ="mark2.jpg" height="150" width="300" /> 
<img src ="mark3.jpg" height="150" width="300" /> 
<img src ="mark4.jpg" height="150" width="300" /> 
<img src ="watson1.jpg" height="150" width="300" /> 
<img src ="watson2.jpg" height="150" width="300" /> 
<img src ="watson3.jpg" height="150" width="300" /> 
<img src ="watson4.jpg" height="150" width="300" /> 
<img src ="watson5.jpg" height="150" width="300" /> 
<img src ="morgan1.jpg" height="150" width="300" /> 
<img src ="nyong1.jpg" height="150" width="300" /> 
<img src ="lion1.jpg" height="150" width="300" />
```

Comment: You will need some JavaScript or [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for that behavior.

Comment: you just have added the images. What have you done to enlarge the images so far?

Comment: but I dont see any javascript efforts

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum. You should show at least some minimal efforts you tried so far and give some more detailed information. You may also want to read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Note that the height and width of the images can be set via the following CSS: `img { height: 150px; width: 300px; }`.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I don't know Javascript. I've edited my question.

Comment: It's silly to downvote, or even close this. If StackOverflow is the "Site You Go To When You Only Want to Follow Draconian Rules", then by all means downvote it. I come here to learn, and I've learned. +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add all the images to a container, for example:

```
<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src ="lion1.jpg" height="150" width="300" />
</div>
```

Then set some CSS that does something to all `<img>` tags in that container when hovered:

```
.imageContainer > img:hover {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

I have not tried this but I think it might get you on the right track to experiment yourself.

Comment: Let me try this. I'll get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PRP95/.

Answer (score 31):

One possibililty using hover only is to use `transform:scale`

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/mJ6Vc/2/)

**CSS**

```
img {
    transition:transform 0.25s ease;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* or some other value */
    transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: This is good if you do not want the images to push eachother. Nice addition!

Answer (score 3):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shubhambhave/6YmMu/)

HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div id="rightImage">
    <a href="www. abc.com" target="_blank"> <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/703327d6394d273e741186dbc0109f4f?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="image"/></a>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
#rightImage  
{  
  height:275px;  
  float:left;  
  position:relative;  
}  
#rightImage:hover img  
{  
  height: 300px;  
}
```